# protect resources from download

Tags: scorm

I'm working on student portal which must have resources section.

This section/resources must be protected from downloads/shares.

For example materials for reading can't be downloaded, videos also

Is it possible protect resources by SCROM and how? Or is there any other way to protect readable or video content ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no... any content that is visible in the browser can be downloaded or copied one way or another. All you can do is make it harder for the person and hope they give up before they succeed.

SCORM has no effect on whether a file can be downloaded.